# Handling many sequential "scenes" in QML

Tags: qt, video

I'm working on a QT project that can be effectively summarized as a long sequence of "scenes" playing one after another in sequence. Each scene can be composed of any number of videos and images, and there are a whole bunch of them.

I figured it would be best to load each scene as required using a Loader element rather than creating everything and switching between them by setting opacity. (Let me know if this is silly. I'm new to QML.)

It seems to work, but I'm getting a visible flash between scenes. Assuming it was a delay incurred by loading the Loader, I tried using two Loaders. I would load the next scene in an invisible Loader, then swap in the onLoaded() callback. Still flashes.

Any QML masters have any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing. It seems to work pretty well.

I define all the Video elements in advance, but with no source property. When I want to display the next video, I place it over-top of the currently playing video, and set its source. I then start a timer that unloads the previous video after 100ms by setting its source to ''. This creates seamless playback, since the last frame of the first video is visible until the next video begins.

Answer (score 1):

You should be changing the `source` property to the url of the next video, not having multiple `Video` elements.

Comment: That's a reasonable answer, given the description of my problem. Unfortunately, I oversimplified a bit.

Really, what I'm doing is playing a series of "scenes." Each scene can be composed of any number of images and videos. This is why I wanted to defined a single Loader and swap scenes in and out by changing the Loader's source.

I will update my question.

Comment: Furthermore, just changing the source of the same video element also displays a visible gap between videos. Frustrating.

Comment: @Michael I think you might need to delve into Qt's source and figure out if there are any workarounds. Eventually you might have to patch Qt.